# My Android XML files can't find ActionBarSherlock themes

Tags: android, android-manifest, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to develop an app with ActionBarSherlock and everything works except the theming. Specifically, I can `import com.actionbarsherlock.app.*`, extend `SherlockActivity`, but I always have this error in my manifest:

```
Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value
'@style/Theme.Sherlock').
```

I know there have been plenty of questions asked about this, but they have not worked for me. I have tried

- refreshing the workspace
- cleaning all of my projects
- putting the line in both the `<activity>` and the `<application>`
- setting my targetSdkVersion and minSdkVersion to various values, in both my manifest and ABS's

and I've tried the following variations, and probably others:

- `android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`
- `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Sherlock"`
- `theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock"`
- `theme="@android:style/Theme.Sherlock"`
- `theme="@theme/Theme.Sherlock"`
- `theme="@android:theme/Theme.Sherlock"`

It's worth noting that the autocomplete after I typed `"@style/"` was showing nothing, so I tried making my own style in `styles.xml` and then that showed up but still nothing from ActionBarSherlock.

Also, in `styles.xml`, I tried to make my own theme to extend `Theme.Sherlock`, and `@style/Theme.Sherlock` was not found there either when I tried to add it as a parent.

I tried loading the samples but got a JAR Mismatch.

My conclusion is that somehow my xml files are unable to access the ABS library, but I'm at a loss as to how to fix it. Any help hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your project's Properties > Android, are you including a reference to the `com_actionbarsherlock` project?
[image: Properties with library reference]

Comment: *facepalm* I included it as a java library.

Comment: I tried to add it like that, but it doesn't seem to be working. When I open the properties window again, the little green check has become a red X...

Comment: Probably a build error in that library. Make sure its path to the Android Support library is correct for your environment.

Comment: *sigh* Well, this was ultimately key to me solving it. I ultimately deleted the library project and my project from eclipse and added both again, because I was having issues with R.java, among other things. Good lord, I spent my whole day on this.

Comment: Sorry to hear it.  Learning to not entirely trust your environment is a valuable skill. :-/  When I have trouble with R.*, I often either  delete gen/* or delete the R imports and select "Organize imports".

Comment: I find myself so annoyed with the environment. Like I've spent dozens of hours while doing android/java development just trying to clear non-syntax errors out of my programs. I like the autocomplete and the debugging, but the overhead is barely worth it.